# Create a column of unique values from a range of two others columns without macro or VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel worksheet where I am trying to create a column that is a list of unique values extracted from two other columns in another tab. The two columns in question are columns L and M in a data sheet called "Data". Im starting the new list in column E on a different tab.

I would like each unique value to be listed in its own cell in column E. I'm integrating this with another piece of software that won't let me use macros. I (Along with my trusty partner, ChatGPT) came up with the formula below but this returns "0" for every cell. Can anyone help?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$L$1:$L$1000&Data!$M$1:$M$1000, 
MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$2:E2, Data!$L$1:$L$1000&Data!$M$1:$M$1000), 0)), "")
```

Comment: `=UNIQUE(L1:M1000)`?

Comment: That won't work. The UNIQUE function Will let you put a range in (e.g. L1:M1000) but it will want to output two unique lists to two columns. I want one unique list in one column,

Comment: =UNIQUE(VSTACK(L1:L1000,M1:M1000))?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. When I put that in the first cell it does return the correct first value, but when I drag it down the column it produces a SPILL error. ITs not producing the entire list, its just producing one value.

Comment: You are not supposed to drag down formula which returns array vertically

Comment: For the order by row `=UNIQUE(TOCOL(Data!L1:M1000,3))`, or by column `=UNIQUE(TOCOL(Data!L1:M1000,3,1))`. 3 means excluding blanks and error values. If you put the array in `E1`, reference it with `E1#` e.g. `=COUNT(E1#)`.